# Does a weapon need to be all made up of a Valyrian Steel to kill a walker?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

If a regular steel weapon (eg. Needle) is coated with Valyrian Steel, is it enough to kill a White Walker, or would it still shred to pieces?

Comment: It seems that Valyrian Steel is not only (or at all) a specific material, it is also (or primarily) a *process*. A Valyrian Steel sword is not a sword made in the same way as every other sword but just made from a different kind of metal. It's a sword made using a *different process*. So just taking some mixture of the same metal that was used in a Valyrian Steel sword and coating another weapon with it would render that metal no longer Valyrian Steel.

Answer (score 5):

As Todd Wilcox says, Valyrian Steel doesn’t seem so much a metal that exists to be sprinkled on the outside of the sword than, rather than one that was used for the forging of sword, using dragon fire, magic and folding the metal onto itself.

> dragon-forged and made of Valyrian steel.
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones - Daenerys X</sub>

> Only one metal could be beaten so thin and still have strength enough to fight with, and there was no mistaking those ripples, the mark of steel that has been folded back on itself many thousands of times. "Valyrian steel?"
>   <sub>A Storm of Swords - Tyrion IV</sub>

What it is exactly about these swords that kills White Walkers / Others is unclear, the only other weapon known to have killed one was Obsidian. The similarities in these two lie with fire and magic:

> Is dragonglass made by dragons, as the smallfolk like to say?"
>   "The m-maesters think not," Sam stammered. "The maesters say it comes from the fires of the earth. They call it obsidian."
>   <sub>A Storm of Swords - Samwell II</sub>

> magical characteristics that of course real obsidian doesn't necessarily have. After all, we live in a world that has no magic. My world does have magic, so it's a little bit different.
>   <sub>[GRRM interview with Robert Shaw](http://web.archive.org/web/20051103091500/nrctc.edu/fhq/vol1iss3/00103009.htm/)</sub>

Whether Valyrian Steel coated Steel is possible seems unlikely, as its yet to be mentioned or likely to hold the properties that Valyrian Steel swords had, furthermore whether it is simply the material that kills as opposed to the magic imbued in the sword is also unclear.

It seems certain that with the information given to us in the two canons, we can’t be certain of the effect of coating a regular sword with Valyrian Steel, merely that it’s not yet been witnessed.

Comment: I’d say it’s likely they don’t have the know how to layer the steel on top. Also it seems like a bad idea to cost it as one chip in the crucial parts of the sword would render it useless.

Comment: Basically you chip the Valyrian steel on the edge and if a walkers weapon touches that part again bye bye weapon and expensive steel

Comment: So does that mean that Oathkeeper and Widow's Wail are not Valyrian Steel? (As both swords were remade from Ice but not with the correct Valyrian-steelmaking process as this is a lost art?)

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister they most definitely are, the art of re-forging Valyrian Steel was said to exist still, but only amongst the most skilled of Blacksmiths. Forging Valyrian Steel from new was considered a lost art.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister In the books Tobho Mott is the character who reforges Ice and he is from Qohor. Qohor is a city in Essos that still boasts about being able to rework Valyrian Steel and Tobho states he apprenticed there. Tobho also states he uses spells when reforging Ice so I'm pretty sure the swords are full Valyrian steel.

Comment: *"we live in a world that has no magic"* :-o GRMM said that? How oblivious.... he doesn't know :-D